# Material UI Button Returning an error when using creatMuiTheme

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Why is this returning an error?

```js
const btn = createMuiTheme({Button: {borderRadius: 100%},});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the `Button` to `MuiButton`.

Refer this link. https://mui.com/customization/theme-components/#css

```
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    // Name of the component
    MuiButton: {
      styleOverrides: {
        // Name of the slot
        root: {
          // Some CSS
          borderRadius: '100%' 
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: thank you my guy!

Comment: what does name of the slot mean?

Comment: Basically CSS property which you want to change. For the case of button visit this. https://mui.com/api/button/#css

Comment: For all other modification you'll be able to check the API page of each component. That should guide you.

Comment: gotcha, so i copied and pasted exactly what you put, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Are you trying to change this for a single button or for entire platform? If you're making this change it will affect the entire platform.

Comment: For individuals just add style using `sx` prop of material

Comment: For theme, its better to set that theme while setting the ThemeProvider.

Comment: To set the global theme, refer this project. Especially this file.  https://github.com/minimal-ui-kit/material-kit-react/blob/main/src/theme/index.js

Comment: gotcha makes sense, thanks!